# How to implement shared memory in shell scripting?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shared-memory

I have a shell script which gets triggerred and runs at regular interval again and again on linux system, say every 45 mins. I need to share certain information between different runs of this shell script. What are different ways I can implement this? This is somewhat similar to interprocess communication. I dont want to use disk I/O so no file creation. Something I can create in memory and can keep it alive for some time duration e.g. 7AM to 12AM etc. During this time, the scripts runs say 20 times and uses/populates that data structure again and again. The values populated in previous run need to be used in next run by the script.

Basically I am looking for something which works like DB but faster and modifying that is less expensive operation. So I will keep my data in that DB like thing and all differnt runs of script will read/modify that thing instead of going to DB again and again. /dev/shm looks good option unless someone suggests better option.

Comment: Why don't you want to use files?

Comment: Using shell is not the right tool for this requirement.

Comment: You could use tmpfs (like /dev/shm) but that's in virtual memory and may get swapped in 45 mins if there is other usage on that system. `echo $BASHPID; $(echo $BASHPID >/dev/shm/foo); cat /dev/shm/foo; rm -f /dev/shm/foo`

Comment: @melpomene I dont want to use I/O operation as this job is time critical.

Comment: If it's time critical, why are you using a shell script for this?

Comment: Internal functionality is written in java. Shell script is only triggering the main functionality repeatedly at regular interval.

Comment: Sounds like a job for Redis - an in-memory datastructure server with bindings for shell, PHP, Python, C, C++, Java...

Answer (score 11):

> I dont want to use disk I/O so no file creation.

If you're on a Linux system, create a file in `/dev/shm`. Files stored in this directory are only stored in shared memory; they are not written to disk.

Depending on your system configuration, `/tmp` and/or `/var/tmp` may be mounted as a tmpfs, making them behave the same way. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Someone has commented above that this can get swapped in some time. Is that true? I want control over this file, creation/deletion etc.

Comment: @JamesBond If there's sufficient memory pressure on the system, yes. But that's unlikely to happen for a small file unless the system is _completely_ out of memory.